# Why is $(X^5-1)/(X-1)$ the minimal polynomial for $e^{2\pi i/5}$, the fifth root of unity, over $\Bbb Q$?

Tags: ring-theory, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials, minimal-polynomials

I have some trouble understanding an example from my reader$^1$. We have the fifth root of unity $\zeta_5=e^{2\pi i/5}$, so by definition $\zeta_5^5=1$.

Then I want to find its minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$. I know that $\zeta_5$ is zero of $(X^5-1)$. I see that $1, \zeta_5,\zeta_5^2, \zeta_5^3, \zeta_5^4$ are zeros of this polynomial. My reader however gives $(X^5-1)/(X-1)=X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1$ as the minimal polynomial. **Why?** I think I had to see that $(X^5-1)$ was reducible or something? How do I see that. And once I notice it, how do I confirm that $\zeta_5$ is a zero of $X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1$, and how do I confirm that also $\zeta_5^2, \zeta_5^3, \zeta_5^4$ are zeros of it? These zeros belong to $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)$.

Once I understand this:
By some theorem I know that the number of zeros of a minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is the order of the group $|\text{Gal}(K(\alpha)/K)|$ for some field K. So we have $|\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)/\mathbb{Q}$)|=4.

We then see that $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)/\mathbb{Q})=\mathbb\{\text{id},\sigma,\sigma^2,\sigma^3\}$ where $\sigma$ is a $K$-automorphism$^1$ given by $\sigma:\zeta\mapsto\zeta^3$. How and why did they pick/find this $K$-automorphism?

$1:$ Example 8.2.11 from *Rings and Galois Theory*, 2018, Department of Mathematics, Utrecht University

$2:$

> Let $K$ be a field and $L$ a finite extension. An automorphism $\sigma: L\to L$ is called a $K$-automorphism if it is a field isomorphism with the additional property that $\sigma(x)=x$ for all $x\in K$.

Comment: $x^5-1$ has a root at $x=1$ so it can't be irreducible.  Do you truly find it difficult to decide whether $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ has a root at $x=1$?

Comment: @lulu Made an edit. I only find it difficult to determine and confirm the other zeros. I wrote that about the root 1 to show the difference between the first reducible polynomial and the second irreducible polynomial.

Comment: If $\zeta^5=1$, what do you reckon $(\zeta^2)^5$ is?

Comment: If $a,b$ are distinct roots of a polynomial $p(x)$, and $p(x)=(x-a)\times q(x)$, then $q(b)=0$ since fields have no zero divisors.

Comment: Worth noting:  it is not obvious that $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$.  It has no rational roots so, if it factored, it would have to be as the product of two quadratics.  You can then rule that out by trying to solve for the coefficients of the quadratics.  [Eisenstein's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) gives an "easy" way to settle the point but, of course, it requires proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only observation you need for all of these conclusions is the *very* basic one that

> For $f\in k[X]$ and $\alpha\in k$ you have $f(\alpha)=0$ if and only if $x-\alpha$ divides $f$.

Because $\zeta^5=1$ by construction, clearly the minimal polynomial of $\zeta$ divides $X^5-1$. As you note, you can *see* that $1$, $\zeta$, $\zeta^2$, $\zeta^3$ and $\zeta^4$ are roots of this polynomial. By the observation above this means
$$X^5-1=(X-1)(X-\zeta)(X-\zeta^2)(X-\zeta^3)(X-\zeta^4)Q,$$
for some $Q\in\Bbb{Q}[X]$, and comparing degrees and leading coefficients shows that $Q=1$. This also immediately shows that $X^5-1$ is not irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$, because it has a linear factor $X-1$. It follows that the minimal polynomial of $\zeta$ divides
$$\frac{X^5-1}{X-1}=X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1,$$
and by looking at the factorization above we see tht
$$X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1=(X-\zeta)(X-\zeta^2)(X-\zeta^3)(X-\zeta^4).$$
This shows that $\zeta$, $\zeta^2$, $\zeta^3$ and $\zeta^4$ are all zeros of $X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1$. To conclude that this is the minimal polynomial, it remains to prove that it is irreducible; this follows from the fact that
$$(X+1)^4+(X+1)^3+(X+1)^2+(X+1)+1=X^4+5X^3+10X^2+10X+5,$$
is Eisenstein at $p=5$.

---

As for picking this field automorphism; because a field automorphism is $\Bbb{Q}$-linear and $K:=\Bbb{Q}(\zeta)$ is spanned by the powers of $\zeta$ as a $\Bbb{Q}$-vector space, a field automorphism $\sigma$ of $K$ is uniquely determined by $\sigma(\zeta)$. Because $\zeta$ is a zero of $X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1$ it follows that
$$\sigma(\zeta)^4+\sigma(\zeta)^3+\sigma(\zeta)^2+\sigma(\zeta)+1=\sigma(\zeta^4+\zeta^3+\zeta^2+\zeta+1)=\sigma(0)=0,$$
which shows that $\sigma(\zeta)$ is also a zero of $X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1$, so $\sigma(\zeta)=\zeta^k$ for some $k\in\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Comment: First of all, a very clear answer, thank you. Why does the quintic $X^5-1$ have at most five roots in $\mathbb{C}$, doesn't it always have five complex roots? Or did you write this just to emphasize that you'd already found all roots?

Comment: @TheCodingWombat I phrased it this way because a polynomial could have double roots. I have rephrased it now to refer more directly to the first observation.

Answer (score 2):

First, the minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ of some element $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ must be, by definition, monic and irreducible. If we have $p(\alpha)=0$ for some polynomial $p\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$ then we know that the minimal polynomial is a factor of $p$. In your case, $p(X):=X^5-1$ is the obvious candidate: if it were irreducible it would be the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_5$, but it is not as $1\in\mathbb{Q}$ is also a fifth root of unity, so we have at least to discard $1$. We divide $p(X)$ by $X-1$ and get $q(X)=X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1$, which may be irreducible or not. We know that $p(X)=(X-1)q(X)$, hence if $\beta\neq1$ is a root of $p$ then $0=p(\beta)=(\beta-1)q(\beta)$ implies $q(\beta)=0$, so the roots of $q$ are the $5$-roots of unity which are not $1$. None of them is a rational number, so $q$ is not the product of a linear factor and a third degree polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$, but it could yet be the product of two polynomials of degree $2$. Eisenstein's criterion allows to prove the following result: if $p$ is prime, then $X^{p-1}+\cdots+X+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ (i.e., the irreducible polynomial of a $p$-root of unity is found dividing $X^p-1$ by $X-1$).

What happens with $n$-roots of unity when $n$ is not necessarily prime? Perhaps you'd like to take a look at [cyclotomic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial).

Comment: Thanks for the further analysis on why $X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1$ isn't reducible in $\mathbb{Q}$.