# Finding the minimal polynomial of $e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to determine the minimal polynomial of $e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}$.

$e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}=x$

$e^{2 \pi i}=x^3$

$1=x^3$

$x^3-1=0$

Now my problem is that I can not prove that $x^3-1$ is irreducible.
Does anyone know how to show this?

Comment: Note that $x=1$ is a root of $x^3-1$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Oh, right. This means that $\frac{x^3-1}{x-1}=x^2+x+1$ is the minimal polynomial?

Comment: $x^2+x+1$ is the minimal polynomial

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$x=1$ is a root of $x^3-1$, so in fact $\dfrac{x^3-1}{x-1}=x^2+x+1$ is the minimal polynomial of $e^{\frac{2\pi i}3}$.

Comment: Are you sure this particular question hasn't been covered earlier? Did you search at all?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:  I searched and didn't find a duplicate.  How about you?

Comment: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3171707/11619), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3962210/11619). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial). This is just too basic to be deserving an answer even if there is no exact duplicate. I didn't look hard at all.